# How to Convert XML file to CSV using NIFI

Tags: xml, csv, apache-nifi

How to Convert XML file to CSV using NIFI
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddKsU.png)

Comment: Please put some more effort in to your question if you want better answers. What about your flow doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ConvertRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ConvertRecord/index.html) with a XMLReader and a CSVRecordSetWriter

Comment: I used that. But the output does not comes as CSV file. I attached the Image in the question

Comment: Your picture does not tell us any information, you need to show us inputs, outputs, any errors, otherwise I can't advise any further - your question only asks how to do it, which I've answered

Comment: could you provide any tutotial or something I can go through. In here I don't have the access to upload images!

Comment: Try here https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Convert-CSV-to-JSON-Avro-XML-using-ConvertRecord-Apache-NiFi/ta-p/246607